# Can't save attribute for triple nested Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for help with creating and saving an object. 
I have three related models, WorkoutType, ExerciseType, and WeightUnit:

```
class WorkoutType < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :exercise_type_attributes, :workout_type_id, :weight_unit_id
    has_many :exercise_types, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercise_types
end

class ExerciseType < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :workout_type_id, :weight_unit_id
    belongs_to :workout_type
    has_many :exercises
    belongs_to :weight_unit
end

class WeightUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :exercise_types
end
```

These are the relevant table schemas:

```
create_table "workout_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "type_name"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "public"
    t.text     "description"
    t.boolean  "is_visible"
  end

create_table "exercise_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "sets"
    t.integer  "reps"
    t.integer  "workout_type_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "load"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "weight_unit_id"
  end

create_table "weight_units", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.decimal "conversion_factor_to_lb", precision: 10, scale: 4
  end
```

A WorkoutType is created using a form that incorporates ExerciseTypes and WeightUnits shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynBYz.jpg).

A new `WorkoutType` is created in the `new` method of `WorkoutTypesController`:

```rb
def new
    @workout_type = WorkoutType.new
    @exercise_types = Array.new(10) { @workout_type.exercise_types.build }
end
```

It is saved using the create method:

```rb
def create
    @workout_type = current_user.workout_types.create(workout_type_params)
    @exercise_types = @workout_type.exercise_types
end

def workout_type_params
    params.require(:workout_type).permit(:type_name, :public, :description, :exercise_types_attributes => [:id, :name, :sets, :reps, :load, :url, :weight_unit_id])
end
```

The problem is that, when I save a new `WorkoutType`, the `weight_unit_id` field of `ExerciseTypes` does not get saved. In the terminal, I see that it gets passed by the form as a parameter:

```
Started POST "/workout_types" for 10.0.2.2 at 2019-10-07 22:01:22 +0000
Processing by WorkoutTypesController#create as HTML

 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "workout_type"=>{"type_name"=>"Test Routine 10", "description"=>"<p>uygyu</p>", "public"=>"true", "exercise_types_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"exercise 1", "sets"=>"2", "reps"=>"34", "load"=>"90", "weight_unit_id"=>"2", "url"=>""},
}}
```

But, when time comes to save in the database, I see that `weight_unit_id` is not included in the `INSERT INTO "exercise_types"` statement:

```
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "workout_types" ("type_name", "public", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["type_name", "Test Routine 9"], ["public", "t"], ["description", "<p>great new description</p>"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2019-10-07 22:01:24.429003"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-07 22:01:24.429003"]]
   SQL (0.0ms)  INSERT INTO "exercise_types" ("name", "sets", "reps", "load", "url", "workout_type_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "exercise 1"], ["sets", 2], ["reps", 34], ["load", "90"], ["url", ""], ["workout_type_id", 23], ["created_at", "2019-10-07 22:11:11.522873"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-07 22:11:11.522873"]]
```

After saving, `weight_unit_id` for the WorkoutType is `nil`. I'm guessing that I need to create the WeightUnits objects in the create method. But how can I do that?

Comment: You are receiveng a `weight_unit_id` but you say you think you have to create the WeightUnit object, show's that you have an ID if it's not created already? If the WeightUnit object does not exists then you have to nest it's attributes with a form_for inside the excercise_type subform and use accept_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: Thank you @arieljuod! I nested attributes of WeightUnit inside the ExeciseType form and added an accept_nested_attributes statement. Now the attributes of WeightUnit are actually nested in the displayed parameters. But now I get an error thrown in the 'create' controller function that I'm stuck on. I posted a new question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58567983/trouble-with-creating-an-object-in-a-triple-nested-rails-form).